# How to create unique keys for react Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

So, I've got this component here, which If I don't give unique keys, React renders it incorrectly.
I can't give this: key={`${name}${index}`} as a key because name for each element can be edited so this will cause remount... So, How I make these keys unique? just giving index doesn't work...

```
{stringArray.map((name, index) => (
        <Component
          key={`${index}_${name}}`}
          name={name}
          index={index}
          onChange={onNameChange}
          onDelete={onNameDelete}
        />
      ))}
```

Comment: If you have control over the ```stringArray``` add an id property to it. You can use library like ```uuid()``` to generate unique id.

Comment: Name can be edited but index is unique for reach item in map so you could use that. You can also just use  key={`${index}`}

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would recommend you do would be to install the uuid npm package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Not sure if you're using commonjs or modules so try both of these at the top of your file after installing the uuid npm package

```js
// modules
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

```js
// commonjs
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
```

Then you should be able to do this instead

```js
// Notice key is now the value of uuidv4()
{stringArray.map((name, index) => (
        <Component
          key={uuidv4()}
          name={name}
          index={index}
          onChange={onNameChange}
          onDelete={onNameDelete}
        />
      ))}
```

UUID is a universal unique id. [Further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Comment: This will cause every component to remount on every re-render because you generate a different key on every render

Comment: Right yeah, we probably want to set the uuids when the data itself is generated